# How to compute $\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X}$ efficiently for large $\mathbf{X}$?

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, cpu-cache, linear-algebra, space-analysis

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. Given that we can only keep $k$ rows ($k << n$) or columns of the matrix in memory, how can we compute $\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X}$ while minimizing the number of disk accesses?

Are there known algorithms for this problem? I searched for external matrix multiplication etc. but couldn't find much.

Comment: The answers you are searching for are pretty well documented in wikipedia articles about [efficient matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication), [cache-oblivious algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm) and [cache behavior of matrix multiplication algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm#Cache_behavior_2).

Comment: @RainerP. Make into an answer?

Comment: @RainerP. As far as I can see those links are not specific to matrices that cannot held in memory, right? My problem is that I cannot keep $\mathbf{X}$ in memory, but can only keep a subset of its rows/columns in memory.

Comment: Since $X^TX$ only involves dots between columns, a simple algorithm suggests itself: go back and forth through the columns (and a shorter run every time, no point calculating every dot both ways around, you already know the result is symmetric). Every time you turn around, for a short while everything is cached. Also the access pattern is completely predictable and contiguous so you can prefetch like mad. Obviously not asymptotically optimal though.

Comment: @harold yes, this is the bruteforce algorithm. We can do better than this by keeping $k$ rows in memory and first doing dot products among them, and then keeping another $k$ rows and so on. This would reduce the number of disk accesses. However, I don't know how to optimally pick $k$ rows.

Comment: Since that is then just picking every pair from an array (the elements are vectors but that's fine), [this should apply](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~tobiasjo/cache-oblivious-johnson.pdf)

Comment: see also [is matrix multiplied by transpose something special?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158219/is-a-matrix-multiplied-with-its-transpose-something-special) / [math.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Blocked matrix multiplication" is one way to optimize matrix multiplication for memory access.

From ["Using Blocking to Increase Temporal Locality"](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/waside/waside-blocking.pdf) by Bryant and O’Hallaron (2012):

> Blocking a matrix multiply routine works by partitioning the matrices
>   into submatrices and then exploiting the mathematical fact that these
>   submatrices can be manipulated just like scalars.

["The cache performance and optimizations of blocked algorithms"](http://csfornewbies.stanford.edu/papers/lam-asplos91.pdf) by Lam, Rothbrg, and Wolf (1991):

> ...presents cache performance data for blocked programs and evaluates
>   several optimizations to improve this performance.

More lecture notes:

- [Matrix Computations (CS 6210): Week 1](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs6210-f12/notes/lec02.pdf) by David Bindel (accessed
  Feb 23, 2016)
- [CS 267 Applications of Parallel Computers Lecture 2:
  Memory Hierarchies and Optimizing Matrix Multiplication](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~demmel/cs267_Spr99/Lectures/Lect_02_1999b.pdf) by James
  Demmel (accessed Feb 23, 2016)